# Domain name redirection with local DNS Server

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

Is it possible to redirect a domain name using a local Windows DNS server? For example if a user query www.yahoo.com it should be redirected to an Internal server.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to achieve, there is almost always a better way.

Comment: It's possible but it sounds like you should be using an http proxy server and firewalling http traffic so all users are forced to go via the proxy. The proxy can be configured to block certain websites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but it is very bad practise.

To do it you would add a new zone for yahoo.com and then add a www A record.

Consider, users and possibly your servers (including mail if you have internal SMTP using the DNS server) will no longer be able find any other record in the yahoo.com domain. You would need to statically add each if you want them to continue working because they will only be able to lookup what is in your DNS server.

The correct way to redirect DNS requests or web requests if that is your purpose is to use a proxy server. Some do both DNS and HTTP/HTTPS, but most of the time only a web proxy is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is, if that DNS server is primary DNS for users just add static record

local ip add www.yahoo.com

Comment: That's a rather incomplete answer. The DNS server would also need to host the yahoo.com zone, otherwise it will pass the query on to be processed up the line.